# sudo apt-get update command showing failed to fetch some archive and ignored some of them

Tags: 12.04

I have newly installed ubuntu 12.04 system. I tried to get update using  command but I am getting following type of error messages.

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Unable to connect to 192.168.1.51:3128:

and failed to fetch some archive.
```

Answer (score 0):

After googling a little bit , I got the reason as apt can not handle many software sometimes , So you can disable some software source that you dont need, well for your question do one thing just go `Ubuntu-software-center` and click on edit then `Software Sources` -

In that `Software Sources` click on `Other Software` tab and disable all PPA repositories except official Ubuntu repositories.

Enabling non-official PPA repositories may cause package manager to become unstable.

Answer gathered from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure) in step 2.
hope it will work.